# How do I access the Rack environment from within Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rack, middleware

I have a Rack application that looks like this:

```
class Foo
  def initialize(app)
    @app = app
  end
  def call(env)
    env["hello"] = "world"
    @app.call(env)
  end
end
```

After hooking my Rack application into Rails, how do I get access to `env["hello"]` from within Rails?

**Update**: Thanks to Gaius for the answer.  Rack and Rails let you store things for the duration of the request, or the duration of the session:

```
# in middleware
def call(env)
  Rack::Request.new(env)["foo"] = "bar"  # sticks around for one request

  env["rack.session"] ||= {}
  env["rack.session"]["hello"] = "world" # sticks around for duration of session
end

# in Rails
def index
  if params["foo"] == "bar"
    ...
  end
  if session["hello"] == "world"
    ...
  end
end
```

Comment: Are you certain that `Rack::Request.new(env)["foo"] = "bar"` changes anything on Rails' end? From what I can see from the source, all that should change is an instance variable on the the `Rack::Request` object itself. Even [the docs for that method](http://rubydoc.info/github/rack/rack/master/Rack/Request#%5B%5D%3D-instance_method) say: "Note that modifications will not be persisted in the env. Use update_param or delete_param if you want to destructively modify params."

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you can use the `Rack::Request` object for passing request-scope variables:

```
# middleware:
def call(env)
  request = Rack::Request.new(env) # no matter how many times you do 'new' you always get the same object
  request[:foo] = 'bar'
  @app.call(env)
end

# Controller:
def index
  if params[:foo] == 'bar'
    ...
  end
end
```

Alternatively, you can get at that "`env`" object directly:

```
# middleware:
def call(env)
  env['foo'] = 'bar'
  @app.call(env)
end

# controller:
def index
  if request.env['foo'] == 'bar'
    ...
  end
end
```

Comment: (I know it's old) I believe the first statement isn't true any more (Rails 4+). `Rack::Request.new(env)` returns new object each time, therefore you can't persist anything inside it. [sources](https://github.com/rack/rack/blob/master/lib/rack/request.rb)

Answer (score 28):

**Short answer:** Use `request.env` or `env` inside a controller.

### Long answer:

According to the [Rails Guide on Rails controllers](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#the-request-object), ActionController provides a `request` method that you can use to access information about the current HTTP request your controller is responding to.

Upon further inspection of the docs for [`ActionController::Base#request`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Base.html#method-i-request), we see that it "Returns an ActionDispatch::Request instance that represents the current request."

If we look at the docs for [`ActionDispatch::Request`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Request.html), we see that it inherits from [`Rack::Request`](http://rubydoc.info/github/rack/rack/master/frames/Rack/Request). Aha! Here we go.

Now, in case you're not familiar with the docs for [`Rack::Request`](http://rubydoc.info/github/rack/rack/master/frames/Rack/Request), it's basically a wrapper around the Rack environment. So for most cases, you should just be able to use it as-is. If you really do want the raw environment hash though, you can get it with [`Rack::Request#env`](http://rubydoc.info/github/rack/rack/master/Rack/Request#env-instance_method). So within the Rails controller, that would just be `request.env`.

#### Digging deeper:

After further examining the instance methods of [`ActionController::Base`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Base.html), I noticed there's not a whole lot there to look at. In particular, I noticed the `params` and `session` variables seem to be missing. So, I moved up one level to [`ActionController::Metal`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Metal.html), which [`ActionController::Base`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Base.html) inherits from.

In [`ActionController::Metal`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Metal.html), I discovered a method [`env`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Metal.html#method-i-env) which had no documentation as to what it did - but I could guess. Turns out I was right. That variable was [being assigned to `request.env`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/2948668bf1509941d7862362ed9c67b95f6cb155/actionpack/lib/action_controller/metal.rb#L193).

[`ActionController::Metal`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Metal.html) also contained the [`params`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Metal.html#method-i-params) method, which, according to [the source](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/2948668bf1509941d7862362ed9c67b95f6cb155/actionpack/lib/action_controller/metal.rb#L141), was set to [`request.parameters`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Http/Parameters.html#method-i-parameters) by default. As it turns out, `request.parameters` isn't from [`Rack::Request`](http://rubydoc.info/github/rack/rack/master/frames/Rack/Request), but [ActionDispatch::Http::Parameters](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Http/Parameters.html#method-i-parameters), which is included by [`ActionDispatch::Request`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Request.html). This method is very similar to the [`Rack::Request#params`](http://rubydoc.info/github/rack/rack/master/Rack/Request#params-instance_method) method, except that altering it modifies a Rails-specific Rack environment variable (and therefore changes will remain persistent across instances of [`ActionDispatch::Request`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Request.html)).

However, I still couldn't seem to find the `session` method. Turns out, it's not in the documentation at all. After searching the source code for [`ActionController::Metal`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Metal.html), I finally found it on [this line](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/2948668bf1509941d7862362ed9c67b95f6cb155/actionpack/lib/action_controller/metal.rb#L130). That's right, it's just a shortcut for [request.session](http://rubydoc.info/github/rack/rack/master/Rack/Request#session-instance_method).

#### To summarize:

**In the controller...**

- Use `request.env` or `env` to get at the raw environment object
- Use `params` to read Rack query strings and post data from the rack input stream. (E.g. [`Rack::Request#params`](http://rubydoc.info/github/rack/rack/master/Rack/Request#params-instance_method))
- Use `session` to access the value of `rack.session` in the rack environment

**In the middleware...**

- Access properties of the environment the usual way through the environment hash
- Access the Rails session through the `rack.session` property on the environment hash
- Read params through [`Rack::Request#params`](http://rubydoc.info/github/rack/rack/master/Rack/Request#params-instance_method)
- Update params through [`Rack::Request#update_param`](http://rubydoc.info/github/rack/rack/master/Rack/Request#update_param-instance_method) and [`Rack::Request#delete_param`](http://rubydoc.info/github/rack/rack/master/Rack/Request#delete_param-instance_method) (as stated in the docs for [`Rack::Request#params`](http://rubydoc.info/github/rack/rack/master/Rack/Request#params-instance_method))
- Update params in a Rails specific way using [`ActionDispatch::Http::Parameters#params`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Http/Parameters.html#method-i-params) through [`ActionDispatch::Request`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Request.html)

Comment: Was helpful to read Digging Deeper portion, especially about params

Comment: `env` is deprecated in rails 5.0 ActionController https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/05934d24aff62d66fc62621aa38dae6456e276be