# Phusion Passenger Server Free vs. Enterprise Version and Thread Local Variables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, multithreading, passenger

Is it expected that the current thread will be the same across concurrent requests to "free" passenger?

I've got a bug in that thread local ruby variables are not independent to concurrent requests. I.e., the same thread id shows for both of two concurrent requests (simulated with a sleep to slow things down).

Is this different for Passenger enterprise edition?

Is there a proper way to get a thread local variable that is isolated for the life of a single request in Rails?

UPDATED:

1. Problem is not specific to Passenger. Problem is there for Thin as well.
2. Other libraries, such as paper_trail may have this issue: https://github.com/airblade/paper_trail/issues/499
3. Here's a potential fix: https://github.com/steveklabnik/request_store, along with a detailed description of the issue I'm seeing.

Comment: No. Even in free passenger, you should not count on the thread being the same accross requests. Free passenger doesn't really have 'concurrent' requests at all. BUT. In general, you should never expect the the current thread to ever be the same from request to request -- but it MAY be for consecutive requests, threads may be re-used.

Comment: I'm not trying to keep a value across requests. I'm trying to keep a value for the entire duration of a request.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a request-local variable, consider putting it into the Rack request env object. See [the answers on this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/848591/how-do-i-access-the-rack-environment-from-within-rails) for a more complete rundown.

Regarding thread locals, that certainly seems like unexpected behavior, but it's entirely possible that Passenger is doing something that doesn't guarantee that a single thread will be owned by a request for its whole lifetime. The `Rack::Lock` middleware usually solves this by taking a mutex around the whole request, but if you've removed it, you aren't guaranteed to have that synchronization. In general, thread-local variables are a code smell and probably an indicator that you're doing something you shouldn't.

Comment: Thanks Chris. Please take a look at the update I posted above.

Comment: RequestStore seems like it's just using threadlocals which get cleared after each request. I'm not convinced that's going to fix the issue for you. Are you using EventMachine/something else that is going to invoke fibers for concurrency, and what version of Ruby are you running this under?

Comment: Because a controller request will be handled by a given thread from start to end, the issue I actually had was that the value stuck around after the end of the request. RequestStore solved that perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Solved:

- https://github.com/airblade/paper_trail/issues/499#issuecomment-83175865
- https://github.com/steveklabnik/request_store

Thread.current[:something] is not as you'd expect with Thin and Passenger!!

Not sure about Unicorn and Puma.

Add the request_store gem, and follow the instructions to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

When you simulate slowing down with `sleep` it also simulates *Blocking IO*, which is when Ruby will allow a different thread to take over processing until the *Blocking IO* is complete.  Depending on what that other thread is doing funky business can ensue.
For an excellent review of the specifics by an expert:

- https://pawelurbanek.com/ruby-concurrent-requests
- https://pawelurbanek.com/rails-thread-safety