# Rails + Rspec + Rack + Session testing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, rspec, rack

Gemfile file:
'rack', '~> 1.6.0'

I am having little trouble in passing the session variables from rspec tests to the Rack middleware. I have gone through many articles on internet but there is no solution which can help me to understand. So basically i want to be able to do this  in my middleware class

`req = Rack::Request.new(env)
req.session[:token]`

But currently `req.session[:token]` comes as empty from my rspec.
How can I set session in my R spec class so that i can test different scenario's ?

Are there any other examples i missed?

Thanks in advance....

Comment: Should it be `req.session[:token]` since you initialized the `req` variable and not `request`?

Comment: Sorry @mryoshiji it was typo. I have corrected.

Comment: This question may help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/848591/how-do-i-access-the-rack-environment-from-within-rails