# How can session info be passed between Rack 1.6+ and Rails 4.2+

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, session-variables, rack

I have read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10451392/263858) in some length, particularly [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10456261/263858). This may be [the same](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29518625/263858), too.  I'm of the opinion that they are for an older version of `rack`+`rails` than I am using now.

I have a rack middleware:

```
config.middleware.insert_before(Rack::Runtime, Rack::Rewrite) do
  r301 %r{^/reviews/company/(\d+)}, lambda { |match, _rack_env|
    company = Company.find_by_id(match[1])

    case company.reviews.count
    when 0
      "/company-reviews"
    when 1..3
      "/#{company.slug}/reviews/"
      # set no_index = true
    else
      "/#{company.slug}/reviews/"
      # set no_index = false
    end
  }
end
```

Within those non-zero clauses, I would like to set a `no_index` variable to be available in the controller.

```
module ApplicationHelper
  def application_meta_tags
    @application_meta_tags.merge(
      'no-index' => no_index_from_rack
    )
  end
end
```

Inside of the lambda in rack, I can do

```
request = Rack::Request.new(env)
request.session['no-index']=true
```

but it doesn't not appear in the controller scope.

```
request.session.keys
# [
#     [0] "session_id",
#     [1] "_csrf_token"
# ]
```

Since similar-looking answers have not worked, I wonder is this due to

- I didn't implement them correctly
- They were done inside the lambda scope
- something else...

I am open to altogether-different strategies to pass data between rack and rails.

#### Update

I am currently using 'ENV' and/or `Rails.configuration` but this is not session-based, and I must un-set the variable after every use.  Even then, I suspect that a race condition may nip me.

Is this a place I can set headers that will be later available to Rails?  I'm trying to understand what is the right concept for passing data between these apps / contexts.

Answer (score 1):

You definitely should not use `ENV` or `Rails.configuration` because they are global variables, and as you know global variables are evil. And as you said you will have race conditions.

If there is no reason to store the `no_index` boolean in the session, you should directly use the `env` variable :

Your middleware :

```
class Middleware
  def initialize(app)
    @app = app
  end

  def call(env)
    env['app.no_index'] = true
    @app.call(env)
  end
end
```

Your controller/view :

```
class Controller
  def new
    env['app.no_index'] # is true
  end
end
```

Comment: Maybe this will work; I'll try soon.  I think the issue may be that I'm not using a `Class` for the middleware, and am instead using the syntax I've given directly in my `config/application.rb`.

Comment: I think you will have the same problem using a class, there is no real difference between a Class or block middleware. I think Rails use his own session system as it can be stored in a file, database, cookie, etc. and it can be signed or not. So I'm not really sure your can access the Rails session that way. If you don't need to persist the "no-index" information then using the env variable is not a problem, some Rails plugins use it that way.