# How to set rack environment variable from inside Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

`rack-cache` gem relies on `@env['rack.errors']` setting to log error messages:

```
    78:       # write log message to rack.errors
    79:       if verbose?
    80:         binding.pry
    81:         message = "cache: [%s %s] %s\n" %
    82:           [@request.request_method, @request.fullpath, trace]
 => 83:         @env['rack.errors'].write(message)
    84:       end
```

It is currently set to `@env['rack.errors'] #⇒ #<IO:<STDERR>>`.

I need to change it to use `Rails.logger`. The obvious opportunity is to hack into `rack-cache` initializer `RAILS_CACHE.logger = ...`. I wonder whether there is a common way to access `rack` environment from `Rails`, like (pseudocode):

```
Rails.RACK_ENV['rack.errors'] = Rails.logger
```

Comment: See if this post helps http://stackoverflow.com/a/23939433/5086701

Comment: @BryceJohnston I was finally forced to write my own middleware to cover the simpliest task of overriding default `rack.errors` `IO`.

Answer (score 1):

The Rack environment is only accessible within the context of a request, hence in a controller or view.

To access the environment you can use

```
request.env['whatever']
```

Be careful when you modify the Rack environment as other pieces of the Rails stack may rely on it.

Comment: I expected there is kinda default settings. Of course, I was able to attach my own middleware to hack into environment, but it sounds both hacky and overengineered to me. Accessing it in controller makes absolutely no sense to me, since I am to override default logging; at this stage there is no controller yet.